# Using a json schema file in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function that needs to validate json data against a json schema. I would like to be able to update the schema without deploying a new version of the function. Where should I store the json schema? Blob storage? Azure App Configuration? And how can I control that the function uses the latest schema?

Comment: Blob storage, simple (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Use BlobStorage or CosmosDb to store JSON Schema. Tricky part is to determine the tolerance on staleness of Cache.

1. If it's OK to have couple of seconds or minutes old cache, then Create a Singleton Class and upon request check timestamp, if window passed then read again from storage. Alternatively you can use MemCache. The drawback with this approach is longer time for new Schema to refresh and different timing of refresh across multiple instances.
2. If you want to address different timing across multiple instances, you can use central cache like Redis. You can add Blob Listener on function app to replace Redis copy.
3. If you want to address the timing then each time request document from BLOB on each request but it will impact your overall response time.

Cosmos is identical to Blob just that in Solution 2, you will need to listen to change feed.

Comment: So let's say I don't have strict requirements about staleness and option 1 is acceptable. I have to admit I don't completely understand the execution context of Azure functions, so I struggle with how I would implement a cache for the schema. Do instances of the function share static variables? If so, would using a static suffice?

Comment: Yes in simplistic design static variable will work. You can read the schema from storage and store into variable. Then timer function can periodically check for update. Keep in mind, there can be multiple instances of functions running depending on plan, scaling and load, so there will be a static variable per process. 

In high traffic app where thread safety is important static may be replaced with Singleton. Also, singleton is easy to unit test.